# How to design Laravel Controller? Example: Order for Customer/Branch/Admin

Tags: php, laravel

Only one Model: **Order**, which is best way to maintain and access control for Customer/Branch/Admin ?

#### Method 1:

```
UserController@order   
BranchController@order   
AdminController@order
```

#### Method 2:

```
OrderController@User   
OrderController@Branch   
OrderController@Admin
```

#### Method 3:

```
Route('user/order')    
Route('user/order/1')    
OrderController@User    
OrderController@UserStore    
OrderController@UserUpdate   

Route('branch/order')    
Route('branch/order/1')    
OrderController@Branch    
OrderController@BranchStore    
OrderController@BranchUpdate   

Route('admin/order')    
Route('admin/order/1/store')    
AdminController@Order    
AdminController@OrderStore    
AdminController@OrderUpdate
```

Which is your choice and any thing to improve?
This is my first Laravel Project.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

example from https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

This is my final adoption of the plan:

// /admin/topics/*
// app/Controllers/admin/AdminTopicsController.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'], function() 
{

    Route::resource('topics', 'AdminTopicsController');
});
```

// /topics/*
// app/Controllers/branch/BranchTopicsController.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'branch'], function() 
{

    Route::resource('topics', 'BranchTopicsController');
});
```